# SQLite: How to select only the filename without extension?

Tags: sqlite

I need to extract the filename without the extension from one of tables I have.

Currently I have used

```
SELECT filename FROM files
```

is used which returns the entire filename (Jessica.Timber.mp3). So is it possible to get only the filename using sqlite(eg: Jessica.Timber )? The files may contain multiple "." but only the last dot followed by the the ext should be removed.

I tried the following query, which provides the result if the extension is only 3 letter long (eg: *.mp3) but fails if its more than that (eg: *.flac)

```
SELECT substr(filename, -4, -100) from files;
```

Comment: You have a design flaw in your database, in that you're storing two items of information (name of file and extension of file) in a single field.  If you control the structure of the database try refactoring for two separate fields and splitting the information when you *write*, rather than *read*, the records.

Answer (score 6):

Below is the query - will get you the file name without extension irrespective of extension length. File name can contain any number of `.` character (Tested and verified)

```
select replace(filename
             , '.' || replace(filename
                            , rtrim(filename, replace(filename, '.', '') )
                            , '')
             , '')
  from files;
```

Test:

```
create table files (filename);
insert into files values ("ph.otoJpg.jpg"), ("ph.otoJpeg.jpeg");
```

Then the above code yields:

```
ph.otoJpg.
ph.otoJpeg.
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no [built-in string functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) that would help with this.

It would be possible to create a recursive CTE, but the easiest way is to retrieve the entire file name and to remove the extension in your code.